# Python recursive no 'in' work around

Tags: python, list, recursion

So my recursive function is too look in a list and see if an item is repeated in a list already. Ex. L = [1,2,3,4,3] return True. I've completed it but im not allowed to use the 'in' function but dont know a work around.

Edit: the only built in functions i am allowed to use are `len`, and the `index` and splice operators.

```
def has_repeats(L):
    if L == []:
        return False
    elif L[0] in L[1:]:
        return True
    else:
        return has_repeats(L[1:])
    return False
```

Comment: Use `collections.Counter` and check whether any of the counts are >= 2.

Comment: you could break your problem down more: what you really want to know is how you check if `L[0]` is in `L[1:]`, right?

Comment: @Shep the recursive function is checking if if the first element is in the rest of the list if not we remove it and continue on if it is in the list it returns True. My problem is i cant use the the built in function 'in'

Comment: there are numerous workarounds for not being allowed to use `in`: you could, for example, just use something like `any(L[0] == x for x in L[1:])`, but  I assume this is homework and the idea is to use recursion as the _only_ looping construct, right?

Comment: @Shep yes sir and ive been at it for a while! haha

Comment: hmm, on rereading my answer, I just realized that whoever gave you this may be more clever than I thought: my answer also has `in`...

Comment: What are the full instructions for this homework? Can you use `L.sort()`, for example? Can you use sets?

Comment: it sounds like you're being asked to do this with purely recursion and `if` statements. You may want to clarify your question, because there are a lot of ways to work around not using `in` which are aren't recursion-based.

Comment: @Shep yes purely if statements other than len or index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider using recursion to compare the list in reversed order that their indexes are the same, since `index` at default returns the first occurrence, like this:

```
def has_repeats(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return False
    if L.index(L[-1]) != len(L) - 1:
        return True
    return has_repeats(L[:-1])
```

Usage:

```
has_repeats([1, 2, 3, 4, 3])
True

has_repeats([1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
False
```

So basically check the index of last item `len(L) - 1` will be the same as `L.index` which should return the first occurrence, if they don't match, there is a duplicate before the last item, and do it recursively.

Comment: @Newb18, as a side note, why I compare `len(L) <= 1` is because if the length of the list only remains <= 1, it can only have **1** or no item, which means cannot have duplicate

Comment: Can you explain what the if L.index(L[-1]) != len(L) - 1: does exactly?

Comment: @Newb18, `L[-1]` is the last item of the list (**-1** is the index in reverse), so `L.index(L[-1])` is trying to locate the index of the first occurrence of the last item. And `len(L)` is the length of the list, since Python list starts at index **0**, so `len(L) - 1` will be the index of the last item in list. And they should be the same if no duplicate in list is found.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to compare the first and last elements in the list, progressively discarding from both ends.

```
def has_repeats(L):
    if len(L) < 2:
        return False
    return L[0] == L[-1] or has_repeats(L[:-1]) or has_repeats(L[1:])
```

This is inefficient because of the double recursion, but it works for short lists.